# Get result of operator predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, operators

I am trying to understand operators.

I have defined the following operator and method for it.

```
:-  op(600,  xfy,  ⧺). 

⧺(Left, Right) :- concatAtoms([Left, Right], _). % _ would the result but can´t be returned without an extra parameter

% concatenates atoms, e.g. [a,b] = ab
concatAtoms([H|T], R) :-
    concatAtoms(T, H, R).

concatAtoms([], R, R).
concatAtoms([H|T], Atom, R) :-
    atom_concat(Atom, H, Res),
    concatAtoms(T, Res, R).
```

The query

```
?- a⧺b.
```

returns true as expected.

Is there any way for it to return

```
ab
```

instead (which was computed by the concatAtoms predicate)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm completely wrong, but ...

```
:-  op(600,  xfy,  ⧺).
```

defines *syntax* only.

(btw, `⧺` (the [double plus](https://unicode-table.com/en/29FA/) is not the same as `#`)

```
?- atom_codes('⧺#',L).
L = [10746, 35].
```

After syntax has been defined, we can write terms like this:

```
?- X=a⧺b⧺c⧺d, write_canonical(X).
⧺(a,⧺(b,⧺(c,d)))
X = a⧺b⧺c⧺d.
```

So much for syntax and term structure, but what is the *meaning* of the above, in the sense of, what should it evaluate to, if it should evaluate to anything?

We evidently need an *interpreter* for terms like `⧺(a,⧺(b,⧺(c,d)))`.

If we want, we can call it `⧺`, the Prolog parser should be able to distinguish a `⧺` in predicate position and one in operator position.

The interpreter predicate takes a 2-arity term with functor `⧺` and relates it to an evaluation result, or fails, or throws an exception.

Here is a (semi-bad) representation:

```
⧺(⧺(L,R), Result) :- atom(L),\+atom(R),!, ⧺(R, Tmp), atom_concat(L,Tmp,Result).
⧺(⧺(L,R), Result) :- \+atom(L),atom(R),!, ⧺(L, Tmp), atom_concat(Tmp,R,Result).
⧺(⧺(L,R), Result) :- atom(L),atom(R)  ,!, atom_concat(L,R,Result).
```

We have now linked syntax to semantics, or at least some form of (cheap) semantics:

```
?- ⧺(a⧺b⧺c⧺d, R).
R = abcd.
```

Now you just have to know when to call `⧺/2`. This depends on what the program wants to do.

In an elegant scenario, one would be able to extend "arithmetic function evaluation trigger" `is/2` to have the above things on the right-hand side of `is` interpreted, as in `R is a⧺b⧺c⧺d.`, but I don't think that's possible.